# Character Encoding in POST JSON Request

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I am sending a POST JSON Request to my application.

```
POST /CharSetTest/Test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8090
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1637b92b-5896-4765-63c5-d04ad73ea9f1

{
  "SampleRequest": {
    "FullName": "関連当"
  }
}
```

My CXF JAXRS Consumer is defined as below.

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public Response testCharSet(@Encoded String jsonBody);
```

But the Japanese Character (関連当) that I sent as POST request is not encoded and results in some junk characters "**é¢é£å½äºè**"

Using SoapUI results in "?????" characters.

This Junk characters differs from client to client from where I hit the request. How Could I encode my POST Request ?

Comment: How do you send the request?

Comment: try set your `Content-Type` to `application/json; charset=UTF-8` and try it again.

Comment: @njzk2 I send my request via Postman Rest Client. The request is mentioned above in the question.

Comment: @kucing_terbang I tried it. But no luck :(

Comment: `results in some junk characters "é¢é£å½äºè"` how do you observe that? (it could simply be your output that uses the wrong encoding)

Comment: @njzk2 I observed it through my log, which is UTF-8 encoded. Also I am character encoding my response to UTF-8 too. That you could see in Produces Annotation that I used in my service class.

Comment: Hello @Elite209, If you just found the solution please share with me too. I got stuck in it too. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Sahil: I solved the problem for myself and posted the solution with a picture. For me, the accept-encoding setting was causing this behaviour. Hope this helps you, too!

Answer (score 27):

Set the content-type to:

```
"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

when sending the post request in the application you are using.
You can find "content-type" in the Header of the URL in that application.

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers here worked for me.

My content-type was already set to "application/json;charset=UTF-8", but the `accept-encoding` setting in my header was causing the error:

#### Disable the `accept-encoding` setting under Headers:

[image]

When I deactivated the last line above, everything worked great! Hope that helps someone.

Comment: what tool/browser did you use to edit the headers like this?

Comment: hi @Mohammad: This screenshot is from postman, which is a popular app for sending requests (among other things). It has a generous free tier, too.

Comment: Thanks @Matt! I was able to find it after alot of searching!!!

Comment: It is a valid request header to inform the server, only that value is wrong in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `json_encode()` options like this line

```
json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Postman returns the message in your language format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/play", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
```

Set `produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"}`  as above, to your `@RequestMapping`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it bu setting HttpServletResponse instance's character encoding to utf-8 :

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

A hack is to make use of the Pre-request Script in Postman.

Paste the following in the Pre-request Script section. This will transform all our params in the Request Url to be encoded.
Thus all the `+` sign would be encoded to `%2B`

```js
var querycount = pm.request.url.query.count();
for(let i = 0; i < querycount; i++) {
  pm.request.url.query.idx(i).value = encodeURIComponent(pm.request.url.query.idx(i).value);
}
```