# How to pass a header with UTF-8 characters?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, postman

I'm trying to make a `GET` request in `Postman` where one of my header parameters has an `UTF-8` encoded character like so:

```
Headers
key: Location      Value: Jcareí
```

All the requests that I made with this header end up giving me a `400 - Bad Request`.

If I just remove the `í` character everything works just fine.

I've already tried to set the `Content-type` to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and disabling the `Accept-Encoding` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127780/character-encoding-in-post-json-request), but none of these seems to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The `application/json` content type does not have a charset. It is always implicit UTF-8. The `charset`param is ineffective.

Comment: TL;DR: you can't send non-ASCII text in HTTP headers, there's simply no standard for it. You can *encode* the header in whatever ASCII-compatible encoding you want (e.g. base64 or percent-encoding), as long as the client and the server can agree on that same convention.