# POST 415 Unsupported Media Type in Postman; UI and JMeter works fine

Tags: api, post, jmeter, postman

So, I have wasted half a day with this and I am not getting anywhere.

I have a German application where I am sending a POST request and keep getting 415 Unsupported Media Type in Postman.

The same request works fine in UI and strangely in JMeter which is pretty much similar to Postman. I have tried all possible solutions listed in the internet including setting Content-Type (application/json, application/json,charset=utf-8) and Accept in the Headers yet the same results.

Here is my request Header in Postman
[image]

and the same request Headers in JMeter where it works (the only difference is I set the Encoding in a different place in JMeter and not in the Header and if I set it in the Header, I get a 400 instead of a 415)

[image]
[image]

Does setting the Content Encoding behave differently in JMeter? the Only place right now where I can set the encoding in Postman is through the Content-Type and that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795748/7574461 ?

Comment: unfortunately I had already. Didn't help. :(

Comment: I think you can use some kinds of proxy tool to capture request from these tools and find out the differences.